# kubernetes external dns annotations

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-route53

Looking at the [PR from njuettner](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns/pull/576)

By adding the annotation `external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/ipv6: "true" , "True", "TRUE" or "1"` should create the AAAA record in route53.

However Im not sure if Im doing the annotation correctly in my external-dns.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: external-dns
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/ipv6: "true"
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: external-dns
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: external-dns
        image: registry.opensource.zalan.do/teapot/external-dns:v0.5.9
        args:
        - --source=service
        - --source=ingress
        - --provider=aws
        - --registry=txt
        - --txt-owner-id=my-identifier
```

Comment: I updated the image to v0.5.9, rather than v0.4.2

https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns/releases

Answer (score 0):

The PR you are referring (https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns/pull/576)  was not yet merged into master and was not released in any of the external-dns version. If you require IPv6, you would need to build external-dns out of the ipv6 branch (https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns/tree/ipv6), but I highly discourage it, as those builds can be unstable and cause unexpected behavior.